Where to find Safe Recovery Module code and ABI
I am currently looking for the code and the ABI of the Safe Recovery Module but I cannot find it anywhere.
I looked in the official GitHub (https://github.com/safe-global/safe-smart-account) without much luck.
For "Safe Recovery Module" I am referring to the module that gets added to the Safe account once "Set up recovery" is enabled.
Steps:

Connect to your Safe
In the left Navbar go to "Settings"
Click "Security"
"Set up recovery" in the Account Recovery.

This process will add a Safe Recovery Module to my account. Where can I find its code and ABI?

You can find more details about the Safe{RecoveryHub} here which can currently (at the time of writing this) be activated using the Safe Wallet.
The Safe{RecoveryHub} uses the Zodiac Delay Modifier as mentioned in the above link for achieving the recovery process.
